# input never gets ng-invalid-class from Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

we register custom-validation-methods for custom-form-elements via an extra-directives:

```
<ng-form name="validatorTestForm">
    <our-input-directive name="validatorTest"
                         ng-model="ourModel"/>
    </our-input-directive>
    <our-validator-directive name="validatorTest"
                             form="validatorTestForm"
                             ng-model="ourModel">
    </our-validator-directive>
</ng-form>
```

It gets all the information via attributes to know which input in which form to validate; then we connect it like that by initiating the directive: (stripped down version)

```
registerValidator(ourModel.form, 'validatorTest');

function registerValidator(form, inputName) {
    var validationModel = form[inputName];

    validationModel.$validators.testValidator = function (modelValue) {
        // validate to true when there are more then two characters entered
        return modelValue.length > 2;
    };
}
```

The our-input-directive is quite simple:

```
angular.directive('ourInputDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<input type="text" ng-model="model">',
        scope: {
            model: '=?ngModel'
        }
    }
});
```

So we run it, Angular does its magic and adds tons css-classes to the form-element and the input-element and when we input sth. into the input, it is properly triggering the validation. The form-element gets a css-class 'ng-valid' when it's valid and 'ng-invalid' when it's not.
**The input howewer, just has the class 'ng-valid' and never becomes invalid!**
So why is that and how can I change it, to reflect the model-changes on the inputs css-classes?


We want to utilize the 'ng-invalid' class to change the style of the input.

Comment: I'm assuming the validation is just an example, if it's not then you can just use a normal text input and use the attribute minlength.

Comment: Yes, we want to be able to add all kind of custom validation-methods via this directive.

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-model https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

> ngModel is responsible for:
>
> - Binding the view into the model, which other directives such as    input, textarea or select require.
> - Providing validation behavior    (i.e. required, number, email, url).
> - Keeping the state of the control    (valid/invalid, dirty/pristine, touched/untouched, validation    errors).
> - **Setting related css classes on the element (ng-valid,    ng-invalid, ng-dirty, ng-pristine, ng-touched, ng-untouched, ng-empty, ng-not-empty) including animations.**
> - Registering the control with its parent form.

Here's a worknig plnkr in the way you do it.
https://plnkr.co/edit/yWlZln2TekdCAhrZ6iEG?p=preview

```
function customValidator() {
   var directive = {
      require: '^form',
      link: link
   };
   return directive;

   function link(scope, element, attrs, formCtrl) {
      modelCtrl = formCtrl[attrs['name']];
      modelCtrl.$validators.testValidator = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
        var value = modelValue || viewValue;
        if(modelCtrl.$isEmpty(value)){
          return false;
        }
        return value.length > 2;
      };
   }
}
```

Comment: While a good suggestion, please expand your answer otherwise this could've been a comment.

Comment: @MaxBoehme Check my plnkr above

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! Although I cannot mark it as the valid answer, because it does not explain the specific problem. And I  had to update the problem as well, because my example-code was insufficient.

Comment: @MaxBoehme create plnkr that shows your specific problem. My answer works as it supposed for your example.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by krutkowski86 try using a ng-model directive instead of the way you are doing it, an example is below

```
<ng-form name="validatorTestForm">
    <input type="text" name="validatorTest" ng-model="MyVar" validator/>
</ng-form>


angular.module('yourModule').directive('validator', validator);

function validator() {
   var directive = {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: link
   };
   return directive;

   function link(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$validators.testValidator = function (modelValue) {
      // validate to true when there are more then two characters entered
      return modelValue.length > 2;
      };
   }
}
```

Please see my Plunker for an example https://plnkr.co/edit/mErINFdPt0odIOdu4Em2?p=preview

Comment: It seems that the solution could lay in the fact, that you do the require: 'ngModel' and I don't. Without using it in your example, it is behaving as wrong as mine.

Comment: Somewhat correct, having another element to check the validity of your form input isn't the standard way of doing it, they way in my example is.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing we figured out the problem:

Although the 'our-validator-directive' was using the ngModel of the input, **it was not using the instance of the ngModel! That was caused by an isolated scope** on the directive which contains the input. (Which I did not add in the example, because never thought of it as a problem ...) Therefore changes on the ngModel of the 'our-validator-directive' did not bubble up to the original one. 
You really have to link to the original one, what is easily achived with:

```
ngModelCtrl = form[nameOfTheInput]
```

Instead of using the required ngModel, which get passed into the validators directive.

[ I have edit the example. ]